# Absolute path reference problem on virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

My image path references (src='/images/image.jpg') inside my .js files  are failing when there is a virtual directory as the virtual directory gets included to the path hierarchy

I can deal with this on other areas of my application where I have server methods to give me the correct path info.

What is a good way to deal with this for .js files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The references will be from the location of the js files; not from the application root.  Assuming you have a js directory off your root, try adding a .. in the path to the image (../images/image.jpg).

Comment: Yes, OP need to use related path

Answer (score 3):

Can you pass in a path parameter to your function ?

```
// in the code behind
  String imagePath = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/images/");

    ...

    <%-- in mark up --%>
    doSomething('<%= imagePath  %>');        

    ...

    // in js
    function doSomething(path) {

     var imageSrc = path + '/image.jpg';

    }
```

There will be ways of making it more elegant but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I created a handler such as this to output some environmental parameters for reuse in various JS objects:

**/Environment.ashx/.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    public class Environment : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(600));
            context.Response.Write(String.Format("Environment = {{ RootPath:\"{0}\" }};", context.Request.ApplicationPath)); // set any application info you need here
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enable the handler in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <httpHandlers>
      <!-- ... -->
      <add verb="*" path="environment.ashx" validate="false" type="MvcApplication2.Environment, MvcApplication2"/>
     </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

Set up your master or content ASPX page (below assumes ASP.NET MVC):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- set up your other JS includes, etc. ... -->
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/environment.ashx"); %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </configuration>
  </head>
</html>
```

Now, for all JS objects and scripts that assume Environment.ashx was already loaded, you can reference Environment.RootPath

```
var imagePath = Environment.RootPath + "images/image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running a flavor of Unix.  You have a couple of options that I'm sure will work, and one that I'm not sure of:

1. Make /images a virtual directory.  This is what I would do.
2. Store a link to /images called images in each virtual directory you use and change src to 'images/image.jpg'.  I don't have a Unix webserver to test this on, so I'm not sure if this will work.
3. Create a subdirectory in each of your virtual directories called images, and store links to the images there.

Comment: Since he's using ASP.Net, I suspect that he isn't using any flavor of Unix.